# Add custom row to welcoming in dashboard

Tags: dashboard

I have one plugin which conflicts with new design of dashboard. I see, that author doesn't bother with support, so I thought I do it myself or at least try.

So I would like to add custom row to this menu in dashboard if it is possible.
[image: Welcoming menu in dashboard]

If anyone could help I would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's quite possible, there's a filter hook in place so we can add our own links in, adjust the following code as necessary..

```
add_filter( 'admin_user_info_links', 'custom_admin_user_info_links' );

function custom_admin_user_info_links( $links ) {
    $links[] = '<a href="http://www.google.com">Example link</a>';
    //$links[] = '<a href="http://wordpress.stackexchange.com">Another example</a>';
    return $links;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: So I can do both of this things in same file as a plugin?

Comment: Not sure i understand your question, please clarify.

Comment: I'm using **Wordpress Admin Notepad**. Recently I updated to WP 3.2 and small issue occured with this plugin in dashboard user_info part. So I'm trying to fix it. I'm trying to add the code you gave into this plugin file. Adjusted of course. Hope it is clear now.

Comment: Ok, so how exactly do you need my help? .. as far as i can tell you can just copy that code into the plugin and be done with it(before the `?>` at the bottom of the main plugin file would be fine).

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Probably the error reason was, that I placed the new code in the middle and somehow broke it. Now everything is fine. Too bad, that there is no way to juggle "Profile", "Log out" links, due to that this added links will always be at the bottom of this menu.

Comment: Okay. So I was incorrect with last statement too. Index would be the solvation.